# Set Action on button to do two action in one click

Tags: java, javafx

Here is the scenario, I have a main window and I click on one button it opens a pop up window. In this pop window I have table view that have some data display in it, and it have a one button called select. After select the data from table view, so when I push the select button I want this pop window to close and the data I selected from that to appear in my main window.

So far only thing I can do is extract the data from pop up window, I want it to close aswell with just one click

```
private void venueDisplay(String title, String message) {
    Stage window = new Stage();

    //Block events to other windows
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    window.setTitle(title);
    window.setMinWidth(400);

    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    hBox.setSpacing(10);
    hBox.setMaxHeight(20);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

    hBox.getChildren().add(selectVenueButton);

    //Display all the available venues to choose for allocation
    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    venueList = new ListView<>();
    ObservableList<Venue> observableVenue = FXCollections.observableArrayList(model.getVenues());
    venueList.setItems(observableVenue);


    layout.getChildren().addAll(venueList, hBox);

    //Display window and wait for it to be closed before returning
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(layout,300,500);
    window.setScene(scene1);
    window.showAndWait();
}

public void selectButtonHandler(EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler) {
    selectVenueButton.setOnAction(handler);
}
```

Comment: How is your data stored?

Comment: It stored in .txt file.

Comment: I created a similar app. I used SQLite to store the data. I think you should use SQLite. make sure your TableView class have an ID variable, you don't have to display this data in your TableView. You will also need a properties table or db. You should store the id in the properties table on selectbuttonaction and/or popupclose. Retrieve that id and run a query on it after popup.showandwait().

Comment: Its a school project, we are only allowed to use javafx and txt files. If I can't figure out one click two action then I will use simpler methods.

Comment: Well you can treat you text field like a db. each new line starts with a unique id and the data that follows maybe separated by colons. The idea is the same it just want be as fast as a db. Ex id : firstname : lastname : birthday. That way when you get the line based on id and split it, the returning array will be array[o] = id, array[1] = firstname array[2] = lastname and array[3] = birthday. It will always be this way. If you are missing data, you would do somthing like => id : : lastname : birthday.

Comment: Since this is a school project the amount of data you have is probably small. Remember, to use a TableView, you have to use an ObservableList. All of your data will be in this list. So if you keep up with your list index on select and return from popup, you can get to this data again by using that index and the ObservableList.

Comment: Thanks I will do that

Answer (score 2):

Please consider this **Example**, you may take the idea and apply it to your program (*Explanation in Comments*).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GetInfoFromPopUpWindow extends Application{

    static TextArea textArea = new TextArea(); // to be filled from the pop-up window

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // create the main Window and some simple components
        // Suppose it contains a TextArea only for simplicity sake

        Button open = new Button("Open Popup Window");

        //simple container as a root for testing
        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(textArea, open);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,610,400);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Main Window");
        primaryStage.show();


        //Add Action Listener to the open Button
        open.setOnAction(e->{ // lambda expression, read more about it in the Documentation
            popUpWindow(); // call the method to open a pop-up wondow(see later)
        });

    }

    public static void popUpWindow(){
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Button fetchInfo = new Button("Finish");
        //create a listView and populate it with some info for testing purpose
        // suppose the info you get from some database
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>();
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList (
                                "First Item", "Second Item", "Third Item", "Fourth Item");
        listView.setItems(items);
        //to select more than one item
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        //decoration and size are up to your preference
        listView.setPrefWidth(100);
        listView.setPrefHeight(100);

        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, fetchInfo);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250,150);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Popup Window");
        stage.show();

        // Add action listener to fetchInfo Button in this Window
        fetchInfo.setOnAction(e->{
            // take the info from listView and fill it in the TextArea in the main Window
            // just for testing purposes
            for (String selectedItem : listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()){
                textArea.appendText(selectedItem + " \n");
            }

            // when it finishes -> close the window and back to the first one
            stage.close();
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();

    }

}
```

**Test**

*Main Window Before Clicking Any Button*

[image]

---

*The Pop-Up Window After Clicking On The Button And Selecting Some Items*

[image]

---

*After Clicking on Finish Button, It Closes The Pop-Up Window and Then Goes Back To Main Menu With The Information (Selected Items)*

[image]

Comment: @Reboot Please copy-paste the above-code to your IDE and try it yourself.

Comment: I think It would work, but my only concern is that popup window I implemented is private void type. Stage method is inside that method and I cannot access it even within the same file.

Comment: @Reboot Why `private`, is that a mandatory requirement in your project?

Comment: @Reboot And why you need to access `Stage` in the pop-up window? It's a local variable and all you need from the `pop-up Window` beside its opening with information, to be closed in one button click and return the information to the main menu, which in this case a `TextArea`.

Comment: Its not mandatory to to make it private, but they want us to make robust programming code and use very defensive approach, so the user can only access the information they need not the method. If I don't make it private the I'll loose marks. That whole assignment is divided in three java files, view is only for gui, controller for event handling and model for the logic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just do:

```
private Venue venueDisplay(String title, String message) {

    // existing code..

    window.showAndWait();
    return venueList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
}
```

and then your `selectVenueButton` just needs to close the window:

```
selectVenueButton.setOnAction(e -> window.hide());
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to perform two operation on click select button

1. Close popup window :

To achieve this set Event Handler on button as below

```
selectVenueButton.setOnAction(handler);
```

In handler you can write logic to close popup  window as below :

```
private EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source instanceof Button) {
                Button btn = (Button) source;
                Stage stage = (Stage) btn.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();
            }
        }
    };
```

2. After click on button you want selected data on main window :

To achieve this declare venue list on Class Level Scope (Member Variables), so you can access outside a class.
in Dialog class :

```
ListView<Venue> venueList;
```

Access data in main Window :

```
CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(); //popup class
dialog.showDialog;
Venue selectedItem = dialog.venueList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the second part, First part worked like charm.